# Reason for return type of void (*signal(int signo, void *(func)(int)))(int)

Tags: c, linux, function, signals, function-pointers

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
extern sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler); // 1
extern void (*signal(int sig, void (*func) (int)))(int);      // 2
```

**1** and **2** are equivalents of each other. This question doesn't commence with **what** or **how**. I grasp well its declaration and what it does from the following descriptions.

> A function taking an `int` and a pointer to a function (taking `int`
>   returning void) and returning a pointer to a function (taking `int`
>   and returning void).

or

> `sighandler_t` is a pointer to a function that takes an `int`
>   parameter and returns nothing. The `signal` function takes such a
>   function pointer as its second parameter. It also returns a function
>   pointer of that type.

Why wasn't its return type chosen `int` or `void` or `something else` in lieu of *a pointer to a function (taking `int` and returning `void`)* to be same as its second parameter? That is, I wonder that whether there  is any reason to opt for the return type.

Answer (score 4):

> Why wasn't its return type chosen int or void or something else in lieu of a pointer to a function (taking int and returning void) to be same as its second parameter?

`signal()` returns the *previous* handler for that signal. So it's useful if you want to restore the old behaviour for a signal after you have set a different handler.

In case of `sigaction()`, the old handler is returned via its third argument; thus it returns `int`.

Answer (score 1):

From [the POSIX `signal()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> If the request can be honored, `signal()` shall return the value of
>   `func` for the most recent call to `signal()` for the specified signal
>   `sig`. Otherwise, `SIG_ERR` shall be returned and a positive value
>   shall be stored in `errno`.

As stated in @P.P.'s answer, this is the previous signal handler for that signal, allowing the old handler to be restored along with the ability to chain signal handler calls.

**Chaining signal handlers example:**

```
typedef void ( *sighandler_t )( int );

sighandler_t old_handler = NULL;

void new_handler( int sig )
{
    switch ( sig )
    {
    case SIGTERM:
        // do your own handling
           .
           .
           .

        // now call the old handler
        if ( old_handler )
        {
            old_handler( sig );
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        .
        .
        .

    // save the old handler so it can also be called
    old_handler = signal( SIGTERM, new_handler );

    // make sure old_handler isn't a non-function
    // (these can be extremely platform-specific)
    if ( old_handler == SIG_ERR ||
         old_handler == SIG_DFL ||
         old_handler == SIG_IGN )
    {
        old_handler = NULL;
    }
}
```

You need to be careful you don't chain in something that can't be called.  For the above example, the code checks to make sure the return value from `signal()` isn't one of the known non-callable values for a signal handler.

There are other issues with chaining, too.  For example, if you install your own `SIGSEGV` handler and use the above code, if your `signal()` call installs a persistent handler (an implementation that doesn't need a `signal()` call inside the handler to reinstall itself) or if you use `sigaction()`, and the original `SIGSEGV` handler was `SIG_DFL`, no call to the default handler would be made.  This would cause the process to go into an infinite `SIGSEGV` loop if a `NULL` pointer were dereferenced, as the invalid instruction would be run again after the handler returned.

Comment: It'll be a perfect answer if you can exemplify the last sentence with a small code, i.e. _chain signal handler calls_.

Comment: @snr I added a signal chaining example.  Note that such code can be extremely platform-specific.